# Why is a boolean value in JTable showing as true/false instead of a checkbox?

Tags: java, jtable, jcheckbox

Shouldn't the new Boolean appear as a checkbox? It's showing up as a true/false string value instead. This is how I'm populating the data:

```
    Object[] columnNames4 = {"Name", "City", "Checkbox"};
    Object[][] data = {
    {"john smith",
     "x", new Boolean(false)},
    {"jenny m",
     "y", new Boolean(false)}
     };
    JTable table4 = new JTable(data, columnNames4);
    JScrollPane S3 = new JScrollPane(table4);
    S3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
```

Comment: you found any solution ?

Comment: not yet :\
under the checkbox column the values are "false,true etc.." no checkboxes

Comment: have you tried using DefaultTableModel instead ?

Answer (score 1):

Create a subclass of[AbstractTableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html) and return Boolean.class in the Method getColumnClass() for the column you want.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup a TableCellRenderer and TableCellEditor

see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

Once you have defined the render's / editor's you can

- define the render/editor as the default render for a Type

   `table.setDefaultRenderer(Boolean.class, new MyBooleanRender());
   table.setDefaultEditor(Boolean.class,  new MyBooleanCellEditor());`
- define the render / editor to a column

      `TableColumnModel tcm = table.getColumnModel();
      tcm.getColumn(4).setCellRenderer(new MyBooleanRender());
      tcm.getColumn(4).setCellEditor(new MyBooleanCellEditor());`

---

- You can define a checkbox cellRender like:

  ```
  public class MyBooleanRender extends JCheckBox
  implements TableCellRenderer {

  private JCheckBox checkBox = this;

  /**
   * @see javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer#getTableCellRendererComponent
   * (javax.swing.JTable, java.lang.Object, boolean, boolean, int, int)
   */
  public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
      JTable tbl,
      Object value,
      boolean isSelected,
      boolean hasFocus,
      int row,
      int column) {
      boolean val = false;

      if (Common.isEmpty(value)) {
          checkBox.setSelected(false);
      } else {

          try {
              val = ((Boolean) value).booleanValue();
          } catch (Exception e) {
          }
          checkBox.setSelected(val);
      }  

      if (Common.OPTIONS.highlightEmpty.isSelected() && value == Common.MISSING_VALUE) {
          checkBox.setBackground(Common.EMPTY_COLOR);
      } else if (value == Common.MISSING_REQUIRED_VALUE) {
          checkBox.setBackground(Common.MISSING_COLOR);
      } else {
          ...
      }

      checkBox.setSelected(val);
      return checkBox;
  }
  }
  ```
- For a checkboxEditor, you can use the DefaultCellEditor class.